# Smile Detection (Any alternative other than OpenCV ?)

Tags: iphone, opencv, face-detection

Is there any library alternative to OpenCV which detects smile.

I dont want to use OpenCV as it sometimes fails to detect faces due to background.

Any one knw other library ? other than OpenCV ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend having a look at **The Machine Perception Toolbox** ([MPT Library](http://mplab.ucsd.edu/grants/project1/free-software/MPTWebSite/introduction.html)). 
I had a chance to play with it a bit at an [Openframeworks](http://www.openframeworks.cc/) [OpenCV workshop at Goldsmiths](http://wiki.openframeworks.cc/index.php?title=OF%C2%A0Goldsmiths) and there is a c++ [smile detection sample](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/1122679/smiles.zip) available.

I imagine you can try the MPT Library for [iPhone with openframeworks](http://www.openframeworks.cc/setup/iphone) or simply link to the library from an iphone project.

> sometimes fails to detect faces due to
>   background.

An ideal lighting setup will guarantee better results, but given that you want to use this on a mobile device, you must inform your users that smile detection might fail under extreme conditions (bad lighting)

HTH

Comment: @George: I have found a problem in smile detection. Is this haarcascade totally dependent on background condition ? because if i am taking live picture then capturing photos successful rate is around 30-40% while if i try to capture any internet image it works fine. Would you like to comment on this.

Comment: I think lighting conditions will always influence computer vision results, regardless of the algorithms used. Have you tried the MPT Library ? It uses slightly different algorithms than haarcascades. Depending on your time available for this, you might want to generate your own haar xml file, using more samples closer to your use case scenario for the training process (for training have a look here: http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html)

Comment: No i didnt tried MPT Library yet. Can you please guide me how to start with MPT Library in iphone ? And yeah i knw light conditions are always influencing vision results. So for this i was trying to first capture face with eliminatiion of all rest of background and then will consider face is smiling or not. But its very complex in itself. Not succeeded yet :(

Comment: I haven't used MPT Library for iphone before(I don't own one and I'll need to upgrade to osx 10.6 before I can use the current iOS sdk) so unfortunately, I wouldn't wait if I were you. Fortunately the openframeworks community is very helpful, and I suggest asking on the iOS forums there if some used MPT library before and maybe get some hints from there (http://forum.openframeworks.cc/index.php?board=25.0). What you describe with haar cascades sound like 2 detections: use the face detection cascade and if a face is detected, use the smile cascade for the face rectangle, otherwise do nothing.

Comment: Hi again George :) I have downloaded openframeworks from Github. I can run all the samples but if I am trying to run opencv example given in openframeworks. Its not working, showing 44 errors and errors are not common too. I think there linking files arfe also missing. Do you have any idea why only opencv example cant execute ?

Comment: hey do you know How to find out whitePixelValue when person smile ? smile haarcascade wont work at all. Need to do something with logic only with white pixels

Answer (score 1):

How are you doing *smile* detection?  I can't see a smile-specific Haar dataset in the default OpenCV face detection cascades.  I suspect your problem is training data rather than OpenCV itself.

Comment: @regilarfry: I am trying to use smileD_haarcascade_v0.05. But its not detecting smile. Do you have any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Egawer is a good starting point if you need a working app to begin with.

https://github.com/Atrac613/egawer-iOS

I checked the training images of smileD_haarcascade_v0.05, an found that they include the full face. So, it seems to be a "smiling face" detector rather than a smile detector alone. While this seems easier, it can also be less accurate.

The best is to create your own Haar Cascade XML file, but admittedly most of us developers don't have time for that. You can improve the results considerably by equalizing the brightness of the image.

Answer (score 1):

iOS 7 now has native support of simile detection in CoreImage. Here is the API diff:

> For iOS 7, Yes, now you can do it with CoreImage.
>
> Here is the API diff in iOS 7 Beta 2:
>
> CoreImage
>
> CIDetector.h
>
> Added CIDetectorEyeBlink
>
> Added CIDetectorSmile